# Track a position within a grid in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a question:

I want to track a position, which can change by using the arrow keys, within a grid in AngularJS, say for example a 10x10 grid. I first thought I would do this in a directive, so I had the following code:

```
angular.module('mymodule').directive('grid', function() {

    return {

        restrict : 'A',

        compile : function($target, $attrs) {

            var rows = $attrs.rows || 10;
            var cols = $attrs.cols || 10;

            for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
                var row = angular.element('<div>');
                row.addClass('row');
                for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
                    var col = angular.element('<div>');
                    col.addClass('item');
                    row.append(col);
                }
                $target.append(row);
            }

            return function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                // Maintain the position here
            }
        }

    }

});
```

This would create a nice grid, however I'm doubting on where to actually put the code for managing the position. I'd also like to be able to maintain positions between two grids, so I thought that something like a PositionManager would need to be created where the grids are stored?

What are your thoughts on where to do this within my module?

Comment: What does it mean to _"maintain positions **between** two grids"_ ?

Comment: For example, you're moving around in grid #1, when you are in the bottom row and press the down key, you need to move to grid #2, so the module would need to know that there are multiple grids and when to move to the next one.

Comment: I think you have some clear picture in your head, but that picture is not clear on this question, at least, to me.

Comment: Yeah that's very probable, I'm should probably elaborate using pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**
**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2w65ynmj/)** (but it's even longer and not greatly documented :D)

---

It's a long solution, so I am not going to reproduce all the code here.
I will provide an outline of the code and a short description of the approach.
(The full code can be found in the link above (also bundled as a module for easy re-use).)

---

**OVERVIEW**

The approach utilizes the following components:

1. **A `grid` directive**
   Displays data in a nice grid and maintains a Grid object representation of the data/element.
2. **A `gridContainer` directive**
   As its name suggest, this element contains grids. It groups grids together,
   so that only one grid inside the container can be active at a time (*"active"* means responding to arrow-key events).
   The key-events listener is registered on this element (and then arrow-presses are delegated to the active grid);
3. **A `Position` service**
   This is used to create new Position objects to hold and manipulate the osition of the active cell in a Grid.
4. **A `Grid` service**
   This is used to create new Grid objects that are able to track their active-cell position and provide utility functions
   for moving around, selecting a cell, determining where the "focus" should go after the activity leaves their boundaries etc.
5. **A `GridContainer` service**
   This is used to "isolate" the grids, i.e. prevent the navigation from leaving the container.
   It also allows to have multiple grids with the same ID on a page. As long as each one resides in a different container, all works as expected.
6. **A `DIRECTION` constant**
   Basically an "enumeration" of possible neighboring directions (North, South, East, West).
7. **Some CSS**
   To make our grids show up nice and "griddy".

Here's how it works (more or less):

1. You define a `<grid-container>` element which contains one of more `<grid>` elements.
   You specify all necessary data (IDs, sizes, data, positions, "neighbors" etc).
   Each `<grid-container>` element has a `GridContainer` object backing it up and each `<grid>` element has `Grid` object backing it up.
   (A default template is provided for the `grid` directive, but the user can specify a different template using the `template-url` attribute.)
2. Once the `<grid-container>` has keyboard focus and an arrow-key is pressed, it calls the appropriate method on the active Grid
   (e.g. moveUp/Down/Left/Right).
3. The Grid computes the new position and changes its internal position representation.
   If the new posititon exceeds the boundaries of itself, it looks for a neighbor in the corresponding direction.
   If there is no neighbor registered in that direction, it "wraps around" (e.g. if you are at the top and press "up" it starts from the bottom).
4. When you click on a cell, the parent Grid is automatically made active and its position changes to the clicked cell.

Easy as pie, right !

---

**The VIEW**

This is what a sample 4-grid view looks like:

```
<grid-container>
    <grid grid-id="grid-1" data="data1"
          width="{{data1[0].length}}" height="{{data1.length}}" x="0" y="0"
          neighbor-e="grid-2" neighbor-s="grid-3">
    </grid>
    <grid grid-id="grid-2" data="data2"
          width="{{data2[0].length}}" height="{{data2.length}}"
          neighbor-w="grid-1" neighbor-s="grid-4">
    </grid>
    <grid grid-id="grid-3" data="data3"
          width="{{data3[0].length}}" height="{{data3.length}}"
          neighbor-n="grid-1" neighbor-e="grid-4">
    </grid>
    <grid grid-id="grid-4" data="data4"
          width="{{data4[0].length}}" height="{{data4.length}}"
          neighbor-n="grid-2" neighbor-w="grid-3">
    </grid>
</grid-container>
```

And here are the partials that serve as templates for the `grid` and `gridContainer` directive:

**grid-container.tmpl.html**

```
<div tabindex="-1" ng-transclude=""></div>
```

**grid.tmpl.html**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in data" ng-init="rowIdx=$index">
        <div class="cell" ng-class="{active:isActive(colIdx,rowIdx)}"
                ng-repeat="cell in row" ng-init="colIdx=$index">
            {{rowIdx+1}}.{{colIdx+1}}:<br />cell-{{cell.text}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**The CODE**

Here is the outline of the code. For brevity, I have removed the actual impelemntation details and only kept the high-level features of the code organization, e.g. object's properties and methods, properties of Directive Definition Objects, comments in directive controllers/linking functions etc:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var data = [
        [{text:  1}, {text:  2}, {text:  3}, {text:  4}, {text:  5}],
        [{text:  6}, {text:  7}, {text:  8}, {text:  9}, {text: 10}],
        [{text: 11}, {text: 12}, {text: 13}, {text: 14}, {text: 15}],
        [{text: 16}, {text: 17}, {text: 18}, {text: 19}, {text: 20}],
        [{text: 21}, {text: 22}, {text: 23}, {text: 24}, {text: 25}]
    ];

    $scope.data1 = $scope.data2 = $scope.data3 = $scope.data4 = data;
});

app.directive('gridContainer', function (GridContainer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/grid-container.tmpl.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function gridContainerCtrl($element, $scope) {
            // Create a new GridContainer and maintain a reference to the currently active Grid,
            // so key-events change the position in that Grid

            // Delegate key-events to the active Grid

            // Deregister the event-listener upon removing the element
        }
    };
});

    templateUrl: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
        var templateUrl = tAttrs.templateUrl;

        if (!templateUrl) {
            if (!$templateCache.get(defaultTmplKey)) {
                $templateCache.put(defaultTmplKey, defaultTmplStr);
            }
            templateUrl = defaultTmplKey;
        }

        return templateUrl;
    },
app.directive('grid', function ($templateCache, DIRECTION) {
    ...

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^gridContainer',
        templateUrl: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            // Return `tAttrs.templateUrl` if it is defined.
            // If not, put the default template into the `$templateCache`
            // and return the key.
        },
        scope: {
            data:   '=',
            gridId: '@',
            width:  '@',
            height: '@',
            x:      '@',
            y:      '@',
            neighborN: '@',
            neighborS: '@',
            neighborE: '@',
            neighborW: '@'
        },
        link: function gridPostLink(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            // Initialize a Grid

            // Utility function to check if a cell is the active cell

            // Upon clicking on a cell, set the current Grid as active
            // and change its position to the clicked cell

            // Deregister the event-listener upon removing the element

            // If the position is initialized [i.e. both !== -1],
            // set this Grid as the active grid
        }
    };
});

app.constant('DIRECTION', {...});

app.factory('Grid', function (Position, DIRECTION) {
    ...

    function Grid(siblingGrids, id, rows, cols, x, y) {
        this._id           = ...;
        this._rows         = ...;
        this._cols         = ...;
        this._position     = new Position(...);
        this._neighbors    = ...;
        this._siblingGrids = ...;

        ...
    }

    Grid.prototype.getRows       = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.getColumns    = function () {...};

    Grid.prototype.getX          = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.getY          = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.setXY         = function (x, y) {...};

    Grid.prototype.getNeighbor   = function (dir) {...};
    Grid.prototype.setNeighbor   = function (dir, neighborID) {...};

    Grid.prototype.indexToXY     = function (idx) {...};
    Grid.prototype.xyToIndex     = function (x, y) {...};

    Grid.prototype.moveUp        = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.moveDown      = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.moveLeft      = function () {...};
    Grid.prototype.moveRight     = function () {...};

    Grid.prototype._findNeighbor = function (direction) {...};

    return Grid;
});

app.factory('GridContainer', function (Grid) {
    function GridContainer() {
        this._grids = ...;
    }

    GridContainer.prototype.newGrid = function (id, rows, cols, x, y) {...};

    return GridContainer;
});

app.factory('Position', function () {
    function Position(x, y) {
        this._x = ...;
        this._y = ...;
    }

    Position.prototype.getX  = function () {...};
    Position.prototype.getY  = function () {...};
    Position.prototype.setXY = function (x, y) {...};

    return Position;
});
```

---

The full code and a working demo can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/2w65ynmj/)**.

<sub>It is bundled as a module (`esGrid`) and all components (controllers/directives/services etc) are `es.` name-spaced (for re-usability reasons).

In order to use it in your app:</sub>

<sub>**1.** Include the IIFE under `[MODULE: esGrid]` in a script.

**2.** Add `esGrid` as a dependency to your module.

**3.** Use the directives in your view:

   `<es-grid-container><es.grid ... ></es.grid>...<es-grid-container>`

**4.** Define your own template like this: `<es.grid ... template-url="some.url"></es.grid>`

**5.** If you want to reference the elements in CSS (or any CSS-like selector), don't forget to escape the `.` as it is a special character: `CSS: es\.grid { border: ... }`</sub>

---

<sub>**DISCLAIMER:**

No care has been taken in order for the proposed solution to be compatible with all the browsers supported by Angular `1.2.+`.
(Yeah, I am looking at you old IEs.)

It's compatible with modern browsers and can be easily modified to work on crappi...erh older browsers
(e.g. replacing `Array.forEach()` with `angular.forEach()` and stuff like that).</sub>

Comment: Wow this is quite elaborate, I was looking for a theoretical solution, but thank you for the awesome example :D

Answer (score 0):

The cases where you should use a compile function are extremely rare. You should be able to accomplish the same thing just using ng-repeat. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in ctrl.range(rows)">
    <span 
            ng-repeat="col in ctrl.range(cols)" 
            ng-class="{selected: ctrl.curRow === row && ctrl.curCol === col}">
        cell
    </span>
</div>
```

There are countless ways you could go about doing this but here is a working example that should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/robianmcd/9otpqbg8/1/

If you click the grid you can navigate around it with arrow keys

Comment: Because this is not an answer. The comment about not using `compile` is useful (but it's a comment, not an answer and you also do not mention one should probably use `template` or `templateUrl` instead). Your fiddle does not seem to work (on latest stable Chrome) and the proposed approach is neither effective, nor does it address the _"maintain positions between two grids"_ part.

Comment: didn't realize it wasn't working in chrome. I fixed the issue

Comment: OK, it's working. I'll remove the downvote, but I still don't like this answer a bit (mainly because the good parts have nothing to do with question asked and the parts that are related to the question are pretty low quality) ! (What a nice person, right :))